# Dirty rectangles - cleared rectangles don't appears again

Tags: javascript, html

I want to speed up my game and instead of clearing all canvas I clear only part (where something is animated).
This is part of my code:

```
this.draw = function(context) {
        context.clearRect(this.oldx, this.oldy, this.width, this.width);
        if (this.type == "square") {
            context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        } 
        this.oldx = this.x;
        this.oldy = this.y;
}
```

ClearRect works but it doesn't clear whole rectangle. And all of squares should be black but they aren't (it seems like fillRect doesn't work but I think it works).
There you can see what happens:
...
Do I use this function (clearRect) wrong? Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you use this.width in clearRect for height too...?

Comment: @PrasathK Corrected, but it is still the same result.

Comment: do you want all cleared rectangles to be filled....?

Comment: yes, all rectangles have to be black. Type of all is "square"

Comment: What value does this.x and this.y holds in your fill rect ...? use this.oldx and this.oldy instead

Answer (score 0):

1. clearRect doesn't clear the whole rect probably because of antialiasing implementation in your browser. I think extending clearRect area by one pixel will help you. Also try to avoid setting up width/height for canvas, this will transform view and some objects may display blurred
2. Regarding to your code, ground rectangles will never be black because in *drawMap* function you call *this.obiekt1.draw* method for only one object, so you cyclically clear previously drawn area. Try to extract *clear* method or create separate objects for every map block.